# Symfony 2/3 : Check user against a firewall behind any url

Tags: php, symfony

I've been looking for a solution to this problem for weeks.

Let's say i have two firewalls :

- The first is named "admin", match pattern "admin/*"
- The other is named "customers", match pattern "*"

The two firewalls are using different providers so an admin is not an instance of customer which means that an identified user can be an admin or a customer.

I'd like, on the front office (not in /admin), to provide special functionality a logged in admin but the AuthorizationChecker and the RequestMatcher are not working since they want an url that match /admin.

I need to have 2 different firewall and providers since i want my users to be able to log in as an admin or as a customer.

Comment: You can probably use [firewall context](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context). This way you can "link" both firewalls, which would make the logged in admin available when behind the customers firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Roles, not 2 different firewalls